# LIKE in IBM Informix SQL

Tags: informix

I have a varchar column "qty" defined in a table "order" which has 2 rows of data as follows

| qty |
| --- |
| 3 |
| 3 1/9 |

When I try to use select query as

```
select * from order where qty like '3 %';
```

both rows which have qty `3` and `3 1/9` are returned, whereas I thought I would get only `3 1/9` which matches my lookup in like '3 %',
I even tried with `trim(qty) like '3 %'` also with the same result; I get both records.
There is no space after 3 in the first row.

Not sure why? Can someone help me here?

Comment: I believe the trouble is that Informix effectively blank-pads the column and does the comparison on the padded column.  Trailing blanks are a complex issue.  In plain CHAR(n) types, if you insert a value with m bytes (m < n), then (n - m) blanks are appended, as required by the SQL standard.  I don't know whether the standard has anything to say about this — it probably does, but determining what it says will hard (finding it will be hard) and then interpreting it harder still.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the info, I understand that padding for char data types, but here I have varchar data type, and I checked if there is a space at the end of record ( for 1st rec in above shown example )  , it has just 3 as data

Comment: I'm not defending what's happening; I'm just stating what is happening.  You provide ammunition to get it changed.  There will be resistance (”backwards compatibilty”).

Comment: Which version of Informix are you using, and which platform are you using it on?  There is a bug CQ idsdb00109716 in the system; if you have support, you can register a case against it, but to get the fix, you will need to upgrade.  The bug has been created, only; it has not been scheduled, much less fixed.

Comment: Informix version : IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC7 on a linux platform

Comment: Thanks for the version information.  It is almost always a good idea to include it in a question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
select * from order where qty like '3_%'.

Comment: Why the backslash?

Comment: Yeah I can try that, problem is old system has similar sql ( as mentioned above ) for one of its searches, but new system we are implementing is in MySQL, So I cant change old system sql , but the same time on mysql I have to interpret user input contains space * ( all variations )

Comment: so in the above informix , 2 records will be returned one is just "3" and another is "3 1/9" 
but  in mysql 
'3_% '  will return all 3<> 
'3 %' will return only  3 1/9 record
(qty =  '3' or qty like  '3 %'); mysql will return exactly same as what infomix returns for like '3 %' in informix.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, there is a parameter you can add to your jdbc url:
`;IFX_TRIMTRAILINGSPACES=0`

In example:

```
jdbc:informix-sqli://dbhost:service/database:INFORMIXSERVER=ifxserver;IFX_LOCK_MODE_WAIT=1;IFX_TRIMTRAILINGSPACES=0
```

Hopefully, it will make the LIKE work the way you want